# Accessing an element in nested html code using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to enter my username and password in my website using selenium but it goes into the timeout exception.

```
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

I have tried accessing my user name(div id "Id" and password(div id "PSD") by using the code below

```
user = driver.find_element_by_id('Id')
```

and

```
user = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(lambda driver:driver.find_element_by_id('Id'))
```

Any help will be very much appreciated

HTML code of the website is shown below:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="panel">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<div class="panel_23">
<div id="msg" class="txt_red" style="display:none"></div>
   <div class="User">
   <div id="Id">
     <input id="Malcom" name="Malcom" 
     style="width: 23px;" type="text"/>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="PSS">
    <div id="PSD">
    <input id="Xmen" name="Xmen" style="width: 23px;" 
    type="pass"/>
    </div>
    </div>
<!-- <div class="txt56">Are you Logged </div> <div class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="cc" /><label for="c1"><span></span>
</label></div> -->
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide the website which you are trying to scrape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `TimeoutException` because of `Explicit Wait` You are using.

Use explicit wait as  :

```
user = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until( EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "Malcom"))  

user.send_keys("username")
```

The another thing is that you are accessing the `div` tag not `input` tag to access username. For passing username you have to access `input` tag of username field.

**Updated :**

Your Login form content present under `iFrame` So fitst you need to switch into frame and then send username and password use following code:

```
driver.get("http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.switch_to.frame(0)   # frame located with index
driver.find_element_by_id("ext1").send_keys("username")
driver.find_element_by_id("ext2").send_keys("password")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='btn_Login']/input").click()
```

**Note :** Please check the syntax as per Python. I have done it using java and its working fine at my end

Comment: Hi Narendra, it did not work, still the same timeout exception. Tried using the By.NAME way  but still the same.

Comment: @ Narendra I used  these user = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until( EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "Malcom"))) and user = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until( EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "Malcom")))                                               I feel that my elements are not being able to be detected. I also replaced "visibility" to "presence" but of no use

Comment: Hi Narendra .. any idea..??

Comment: You want to login right ? So your element present under `iframe` so first you need to switch under frame using `driver.switch_to.frame(0)` and then  enter username and password